# Android: How to remove view from linearlayout from another class?

Tags: java, android

I have some LinearLayout I need to remove its view. I can do it from same class. But I need to do it from another class

```
LinearLayout container2;
LinearLayout container3;
LinearLayout container4;
LinearLayout container5;
LinearLayout container6;
LinearLayout container7;
LinearLayout container8;
LinearLayout container9;
LinearLayout container10;


container19.removeAllViews();
                    container12.removeAllViews();
                    container9.removeAllViews();
                    container11.removeAllViews();
                    container13.removeAllViews();
                    container8.removeAllViews();
                    container10.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: Hello ZenZie welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, it's very hard to understand what your problem is; please read the help to learn how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried anything? Do you know how to call a method of one class from another? If not, I suggest you take some time to learn how to do this. There are plenty of Java tutorials that will teach you how, even if it isn't specific to Android and layouts.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't name variables with numbers. Use an array or `List` instead.

Comment: Also, why do you have 20 LinearLayouts? This seems overly complex. Is this a dynamic view with like rows or something? If so, you should use `RecyclerView` instead of trying to add and remove views yourself.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to add `public static` method to your LinearLayout?

So it will be like for example :
ActivityA.class

```
public static LinearLayout container2;

container2 = findViewById(R.id.container2);
```

Remove the view in ActivityB.class

```
ActivityA.container2.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: `public static` methods should only be used for methods that are not associated with a specific instance of the class. In this case, you should use a normal method on the activity.